# Send Email Attachement using byte[] with Java-Mail

Tags: java, email

I have a byte array wich i wish to add as an attachement to an email i am sending.

Unfortunally i can't find how to attach it as a byte array, the solution i have uses disk files (which i dont want since i dont want to write the byte array just so i can attach it).

I've found one solution that involves creating an object that extends DataSource and use this as a wrapper for the byte array and then feed that to the MimeBodyPart.

Anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Creating a `DataSource` is the right approach. You don't have to write your own, though. Just use the [`ByteArrayDataSource`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) from JavaMail.

Comment: /facepalm i dont know why i didnt see that class, especially considering i was trying to use the other solution and i wrote the class down and named it : ByteArrayDatasource. =S

Comment: @NunoFurtado Can you maybe update your question with a code snippet that works?

Comment: @snooze92 sorry this took so long, here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BbYUAC6u) of it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your requirement...store attachment file as BLOB in DB and fetch that for sending it as a attachment in mail...............

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import javax.activation.*; 

public class BufferedDataSource implements DataSource { 

private byte[] _data; 
private java.lang.String _name; 

public BufferedDataSource(byte[] data, String name) { 
_data = data; 
_name = name;
} 

public String getContentType() { return "application/octet-stream";} 
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException { return new ByteArrayInputStream(_data);} 
public String getName() { return _name;} 

/** 
* Returns an OutputStream from the DataSource 
* @returns OutputStream Array of bytes converted into an OutputStream 
*/ 
public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException { 
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
out.write(_data); 
return out;
}
}
===========================================================
//Getting ByteArray From BLOB
byte[] bytearray; 
BLOB blob = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("IMAGE_GIF"); 
if (blob != null) { 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream()); 
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
int length = 0; 
while ((length = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
bao.write(buffer, 0, length);
} 
bao.close(); 
bis.close(); 
bytearray = bao.toByteArray(); 
}
===============================================================
//Attach File for mail
MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart(); 
BufferedDataSource bds = new BufferedDataSource(bytearray, "AttName"); 
att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds)); 
att.setFileName(bds.getName());
```