# javax.mail attached PDF-File broken

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jakarta-mail

I'm working on a program which is supposed to send a filled PDF-File as attachment to a Mail via javax. For testing I sent the Mail to my own address and the sending itselft works perfectly fine, but the attached PDF-File appears to be broken.

My PDF-Reader told, that it's possible, that the file could've been decoded incorrectly. After some reasearch, I added the lines

```
 filePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
 filePart.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
```

to the code below, but it's still not working.

```
try
    {
        String filename = "C:/somerandompath/PDFTest.pdf";
        reader = new PdfReader(filename);
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("FORM" , ".pdf");
        fostream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader , fostream);
        acro_fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

        Iterator entries = pdfOutputs.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext())
        {
            Entry thisEntry = (Entry)entries.next();
            acro_fields.setField((String)thisEntry.getKey() , (String)thisEntry.getValue());
        }


        /** Sending the Mail */
        try
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host" , "servername");
            javax.mail.Session sess = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties , null);
            DataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
            BodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String mailtext = "This is a Testmail";

            filePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
            filePart.setFileName("File.pdf");
            filePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
            filePart.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            content.addBodyPart(filePart);

            textPart.setText(mailtext);
            textPart.setHeader("MIME-Version" , "1.0");
            textPart.setHeader("Content-Type" , textPart.getContentType());
            content.addBodyPart(textPart);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress("sendermail@gmail.com");
            InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress("recipientmail@gmail.com");
            InternetAddress adressCC = new InternetAddress("ccmail@gmail.com");

            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO , addressTo);
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, adressCC);
            msg.setSubject("Your file");                
            msg.setContent(content);

            Transport.send(msg);
            properties.clear();
        }
        catch(Exception ex1)
        {
            System.out.println(ex1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex2)
    {
        System.out.println(ex2);
    }
```

I'll appreciate any guidance

Comment: You have to `close` the `PdfStamper` before using its output as the output  is completed during `close`.

Comment: In order to check if this is related to the PDF file or the mailing, did you check if tempFile is correct before sending it?

Comment: @mkl Sorry for not including this in the shown code, but the Stamper, as well as the reader and the FileOutputStream are closed at the end. The tempFile is also deleted, when the program finishes

Comment: @ Guy Bouallet Yes, I tested the program locally with focus on the tempFile and it's properly filled and can be opened by a PDF-Reader like Adobe's

Comment: *closed at the end* - You had better close it right before your `/** Sending the Mail */` comment.

Comment: @mkl Oh, misread that, sorry. I tried it out and, just to be sure, I also closed the "reader" and the "fostream". Works perfectly fine now, so thank you very much

Comment: Resource-wise it is a good idea to close the `reader` as soon as possible after the `stamper` but it is not necessary for the issue at hand. The `fostream` is already implicitly closed when closing the `stamper`.Closing the `stamper` is important, though, because it adds the internal cross reference table and the end-of-file section to the PDF. Without that a PDF is incomplete and hardly usable.

Answer (score 1):

As mkl already indicated, you should close the `PdfStamper` instance before using the temporary file to send the mail. Right now, based on the code snippet you shared, it is normal that your PDF file is corrupt: you are using an unfinished PDF.

Apart from that, it is very strange that you are using a temporary file. Why aren't you creating the file in memory? Do something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
// do stuff with stamper
stamper.close();
byte[] pdf_bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Now you can use these bytes in JavaMail as described here: [Send Email Attachement using byte[] with Java-Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804901/send-email-attachement-using-byte-with-java-mail)

Comment: For me, it just seemed to be the easiest way to create a file with little code. But nevertheless, thanks for your answer. Maybe, if I get the time, I can try out this way as well.

Comment: Disk access usually takes more time than working in memory, although that depends on the actual configuration of your server (maybe there isn't even a physical disk in place).